# jquery function shorthand

Tags: jquery

Is there any shorthand for this?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.DoStuff= function() {
     // do stuff        
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This will be placed in separate file.

And than to be called like that from another file from inside $(document).ready( function(){});:

```
$('element').DoStuff();
```

?

Comment: Couldnt figure out the question what is element here?

Comment: element could be anything e.g. h1, p, .somethinkg, #something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could write a [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), e.g.

```
$.fn.DoStuff = function () {
         this === $('element');
         ...
    };
```

here's working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xW3ZD/

Answer (score 1):

not really, you can do

```
(function($) {
 $.fn.extend({
   DoStuff: function(options) {
    //stuff
   };
})(jQuery);
```

which can still be called `$(selector).DoStuff(options);` but it's not a lot shorter and it extends the jquery object rather than being it's own function.

Comment: So, shorthand for this does not exist?

Comment: @Pete sorry, not that I know of